# What is graph of a matrix?

Tags: matrices

What is graph of a matrix?

Our teacher asked us to find out graph of a matrix and didn't give us any further insight but I cannot find any sound definition or data. All I am finding again and again is matrix of a graph.

Is it something related to MATLAB where we plot the matrix?

Could someone please help me with this?

Comment: Matrix of a graph makes more sense at least to me.

Comment: Maybe he meant image of a matrix. You just think about $y=Ax$. If you change all possible values of x and look what values of y are possible. E.g. if $A=0$ then the image is only the zero vector, if $A=id$ (identity matrix) and $x \in R^n$, then the image is $R^n$

Comment: Who knows what your teacher meant, but it might be a reverse of the problem described here [Adjacency matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix).

Comment: Might be easier to guess what he means, if you show us the matrix you're talking about.